# Get remoteEntry.js from custom path in Module Federation webpack plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

Is there a way I can define a path for remoteEntry.js file?
For example:
I reach it from http://myhost.com/
but I need to reach it from http://myhost.com/app/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In mfe index.html change basehref to
href="/app/"